# Pyarrow writing parquet dataset behavior after updating pyarrow

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I'm working on a codebase that processes daily data. We have a Pyarrow Table with 3 columns, one of which is a date. The data goes back to 2007, so ~ 5800 unique dates. The table has 43 million rows, so avg of ~7500 rows per date. The output should be a parquet dataset, partitioned by the date column. So you have an folder with ~5800 folders, named by date. Each folder should contain a single parquet file.

The repo switches between pandas dataframes and pyarrow tables frequently, mostly pandas for data transformation and pyarrow for parquet reading and writing. The internal processing can be updated, but to work with our other processes, the output needs to remain as daily parquet files.

This has worked for a long time until we tried updating the Pandas and Pyarrow version, for performance improvements. We went Pandas 1.2 -> 2.0, and Pyarrow 2 -> 12. The original code, that worked:

```
pq.write_to_dataset(table, root_path=str(output_filepath),
                    partition_cols=['action_date'],
                    allow_truncated_timestamps=True)
```

Now, with updated pandas and pyarrow on that code, I get the error:

`pandas_to_parquet Fragment would be written into 4141 partitions. This exceeds the maximum of 1024`

I researched and found that pyarrow's behavior changed after version 4.0. It defaults to 1024, and must be set higher. Since I know there's 5800 partitions needed, growing every day, I set it to 7000.

```
pq.write_to_dataset(table, root_path=str(output_filepath),
                    partition_cols=['action_date'],
                    allow_truncated_timestamps=True,
                    use_legacy_dataset=False,
                    max_partitions=7000)
```

This took significantly longer to run, many times over. The output folders were correct, but inside each was many parquet files, each only about 2kb. Previously there would be a single parquet, around 20 to 80kb.

I'm trying to figure out how to ensure a single parquet file per daily folder, and have similar or better performance to the previous version with older pandas and pyarrow. The original in memory table I'm trying to write to a parquet dataset is about 280mb. This runs on a larger EC2 instance, AWS Linux.

Comment: after reading all of the above, i am trying to establish what the actual question is or where you are stuck.   please shorten like this:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   and this   [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'm trying to make the pyarrow write_to_dataset method function the same as when it did in version 2.0, and have comparable performance. That is what I'm stuck on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71665989/pyarrow-write-dataset-limit-per-partition-files may help.

Comment: To take a step back, why do you want so many partitions for data that can fit in memory? It might be sensible if the data/day is about to get a lot bigger, but otherwise it's just going to make working with the dataset slower and more complicated than a single file.

Comment: @alistaire I completely agree, and wish I could go that route. But I have to keep the output format and folder structure as-is for now. Other processes outside of my control rely on folder names for dates. It's not great, but it's what I have to work with for now.