# Streaming partitioning into partitions of set size in Polars

Tags: python, python-polars, data-partitioning

## Situation

1. I have a parquet dataset of big size, that does not fit into RAM.
2. I need to split the dataset into multiple partitions defined by a dictionary such as `{"split1": 0.33, "split2": 0.274, "split3": 0.396}`. The result would be a dictionary of `polars.LazyFrame`s, assuming it is possible to stream the results of the partitioning into `.parquet` files.
3. I need this to be as fast as possible.
4. I want to use Polars to do this, in lazy evaluation mode, streaming `collect()` at the end.

## Suboptimal solution

I know I can do a single pass over the data to count them, then another pass `with_row_count()` for each of the partitions and select the appropriate ranges.

## Hypothesis

I believe that it should be possible to do this "on the fly" in just a single pass, just iterating over the data and throwing them into separate baskets in a set frequency to match the fractions.

## Actual question

What is the most efficient way to do this partitioning? I was not able to find a build-in function in Polars nor was I able to come up with any way to do this efficiently.

## Comments

I am thinking of some mathematical expression based on modular arithmetics or residual division, but I can't seem to figure out the details.

Comment: What are the numbers of your split1, split2, split3 supposed to represent? Is it the share of the results per partition? Is it some result thereof? Based on what you said you want to do I think you'd be better off using pyarrow as polars doesn't have dataset writing built in. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71665989/pyarrow-write-dataset-limit-per-partition-files